# Decorators are not enabled @withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I have my React App working on a test environment on AWS, I've come to setup a local dev environmnet with docker but when I `npm start` I get the following error.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Navbar/index.js
SyntaxError: /app/src/components/Navbar/index.js: Decorators are not enabled.
If you are using ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }], make sure it comes *before* "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" and enable loose mode, like so:
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  19 | import DoctorLiveConsultationNav from './DoctorLiveConsultationNav'
  20 |
> 21 | @withRouter
     | ^
  22 | class Navbar extends React.PureComponent {
  23 |   constructor(props) {
  24 |     super(props)
```

Its setup identical to the AWS system so not sure why this error is appearing.  An online post suggested to add the code to my babel file

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['react-app', 'expo'],
  plugins: [
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
],
}
```

but this hasn't cured the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to resolve the issue above, deleting the vendor folder and re-running `yarn install` did cure the issue.